# How to convert JQuery to Vue.js Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to add class name dynamically. That class is changing display of navbar when scroll offset greater than 50.

This is jQuery code (jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll):

```js
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar-default").offset().top > 50) {
      $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
      $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
  });
```

This is what I tried:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isSticky: false,
      stickyClass: "top-nav-collapse",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll(e) {
      e.prevent();
      if (window.scrollY > 50) {
        this.isSticky = true;
        console.log("deneme");
      } else {
        this.isSticky = false;
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.handleScroll();
  },
};
</script>
```

How can I convert this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the scroll event handler in the `mounted()` function and change the `isSticky` variable there.

```javascript
export default {
  data: () => ({
    isSticky: false,
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.scroll_event_handler = () => {
      this.isSticky = window.scrollY > 50;
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scroll_event_handler);
  },
  unmounted() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.scroll_event_handler);
  },
}
```

Then in your template you can add/remove the class like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar-fixed-top" :class="{'top-nav-collapse': isSticky}">
    ...
</nav>
```

Comment: The `scroll`-handler should be cached, so that it could be removed on unmount to avoid a memory leak.